# How could Quark play 200+ Tongo games in one month?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

What is the average time needed to play entire [Tongo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tongo) game? I understand that, due to its nature, one can play a real quick deal and another a really long one. That's why I'm asking about average time.

How it is possible that Quark managed to win **207 Tongo games** in a row during a **single month**?

> **O'BRIEN:** *I don't know about that. Quark's on a roll. In the last month, he's won two hundred and six straight games.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Change of Heart](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/540.txt)</sup></sub>

207 divided to 30 gives 7. Taking average time of one hour (quite hard to believe) Quark wouldn't be doing anything during that entire month except for playing Tongo (even harder to believe).

**What am I missing? Where did I make a mistake in my calculations?**

Comment: Ferengi always struck me as being impulsive. I can see how if Quark can delegate his work responsibilities (he is the boss after all) and just spend an entire day playing he would. He gets a winning streak, inherent greed takes over. Plus do we really know a month on DS9 is 30 days? Maybe 28, maybe 35?

Comment: Mean, median or mode?

Comment: @erdiede Sounds like a good explanation. A bit own-perspective and speculation-like, but I don't think, we're going to find a better / cannon answer. Unless someone has a source to explain how long regular Tongo game can last (maybe just 15 minutes?).

Comment: @trejder It's pure speculation with a few wisps of observation.

Comment: There are 720 Earth hours in an Earth month of 30 Earth days, and 744 Earth hours in an Earth month of 31 Earth days. If Quark played 207 Tongo games straight without sleeping during the month the average length of a Tongo game would be no more than 3.478 to 3.594 Earth hours. It is possible that quark played and won 207 Tongo games during a Bajoran or Ferenghi month. Does anyone know anything about their calendars?

Comment: "Bajor may have a 26-hour day, according to various mentions throughout the series and at the startrek.com database for places."

Comment: Some games could be extremely short.   If you go all-in in high-stakes poker, the game could end quite quickly.  But in poker, your opponent can just fold.   Maybe in Tongo there is something similar, except your opponents are forced to go all-in too and one or the other of you loses very quickly.   This is just an example, of course, but the sheer number of games could be emphasizing that he is so skillful that he can also end the games very quickly.

Comment: We shouldn't assume that he played all the games one at a time.  If we were to look at poker, while typically played one at a time in person, it can also be played online with multiple games going.

Comment: DS9 was on a Bajoran day (26 Bajoran hours/~25¾ Earth hours). It only makes sense that DS9 was also on a Bajoran yearly calendar. According to this well researched but (AFAIK) non-canon [source](http://atavachron.wikidot.com/calendars:bajoran-calendar), a typical Bajoran month is between 54 and 59 Bajoran days.

Comment: @Jeeped - Their months must be pretty consistent with Earth months in order for their pregnancies to only last "five months"

Comment: @Valorum - The source I linked to constructed a Bajoran calendar by cross-referencing festivals with stardates among other information. The 5 month pregnancy seems to be an anomaly in the face of other evidence unless 5 Bajoran months roughly equals 9 Earth months.

Comment: @Valorum - ... or the doctor translated the pregnancy term to Earth months for Miles and Kako's benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same episode, we see Julian buying into an after-hours game. He only has limited funds and he's going to be kicked out if he doesn't start winning big money, really quickly. Although Quark is usually happy to extend credit, a game evidently only lasts as long as there isn't a clear winner, typified by **all the other players losing their money.**

By that logic, a "game" might only last a very short time since Julian goes from ***having about half the funds on the table*** to ***totally crapped out*** in a single hand lasting about five minutes.

---

In order to win 200+ games in a month, Quark might only be playing for a few hours each day, with each game lasting (say) 20-30 mins before everyone's out of cash. A 6-games-a-day tongo habit could equate to less than 2-3 hours per day.